# How do I refresh routes for a ruby on rails app that has 2 servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, passenger

**The goal:** our ruby on rails app dynamically builds routes from information in a table, so when someone edits information in that table, we need a way to refresh the routes on both servers automatically. We have a folder in our views containing templates. A route to that view is automatically created based on data in a table:

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :templates do
  templates = PdfTemplate.all.pluck(:shortcode)
  resources :pdfs, only: templates do
    templates.each do |template|
      get template.to_s, on: :collection
    end
  end
end
```

We want the routes to be updated automatically in the event someone changes the shortcode of a template in the database.

**My attempt:** Previously, I tried adding a call back on the model for `after_save` if `attribute_changed?` to do `Rails.application.reload_routes!`, which refreshes the routes just like we need. However, because our app has 2 servers, it only updates the routes on one server, not both, causing issues from that discrepancy.

**The real question (finally):** what’s the best way to refresh the routes on both servers of our app? We're using Ruby v2.1.2, Rails v4.1.6, and mysql.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt mysql

Comment: I cannot think of a reason to reload the routes if records in the database have changed. Can you please elaborate on that and add an example? To me, this sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887).

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the call out on the XY problem, I've updated the question to help address that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spickermann has it right (especially the XY Problem comment). I just wanted to mention you could also do:

```
namespace :templates do
  scope :pdfs do 
    get '*shortcode', to: 'pdfs#show', as: :pdf
  end
end
```

Which gives you:

```
templates_pdf GET    /templates/pdfs/*shortcode(.:format)   templates/pdfs#show
```

`'*shortcode'` is a wildcard matcher. So, if you have a URL like:

```
localhost:3000/templates/pdfs/a-cool-template
```

It will route to `templates/pdfs#show` with a `params[:shortcode] == 'a-cool-template'`.

Then, your `Templates::PdfsController` might look something like:

```
class Templates::PdfsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    begin 
      render params[:shortcode]
    rescue MissingTemplateError
      # do something here
    end
  end

end
```

If `app/views/templates/pdfs/a-cool-template.html.erb` exists, it will be rendered. If it doesn't, then you catch the MissingTemplate error and respond accordingly. (BTW, I forget what the actual name of the MissingTemplate error is, so what I have there is probably not correct.)

If you have multiple template types, you could do:

```
namespace :templates do
  [:pdfs, :html].each do |template_type|
    scope template_type do 
      get '*shortcode', to: "#{template_type}#show", as: template_type
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives you:

```
templates_pdfs GET    /templates/pdfs/*shortcode(.:format)  templates/pdfs#show
templates_html GET    /templates/html/*shortcode(.:format)  templates/html#show
```

Comment: So in this example, what would you recommend I put in the `show` action to then render the view `app/views/templates/pdfs/a-cool-template.html.erb` since there isn't a route for it specifically?

Comment: Added `Template::PdfsController#show` to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you just allow all routes and handle 404 in the controller?

I would change the `config/routes.rb` to something like this:

```
get 'templates/pdfs/:shortcode', to: 'pfds#routing', via: :get
```

And add a method like this to the `PdfsController`:

```
def routing
  pfd_template = PdfTemplate.find_by!(shortcode: params[:shortcode])
  # code needed to handle the shortcode
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be multiple ways to achieve this, but what I would do is simply add a trigger to your mysql database to call an API endpoint which in turn updates the routes.

An example of using mysql triggers to make http calls: [can be found here](http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1497)